# Changing windows in the python part of Kivy, when using KV file

Tags: python, kivy

I am having trouble working out how to change screens in kivy. I have an IF statement in the python code, and want to change screens based on the result of that. Along with my KV file. In the IF statement, that is all working, and it prints "success", but the line "WindowManager.current = 'homewindow'" just does not do anything, nor does it throw any errors, just does nothing?

I am obviously missing something (or misunderstanding), I have tried all manner of things but cannot get it to fire. Please help! I am obviously new to OOP....

KV file

```
WindowManager:
    SplashWindow:
    WelcomeWindow:
    HomeWindow:

<SplashWindow>:
    name: "splash"
    Label:
        text: "Welcome to the App"

<WelcomeWindow>:
    name: "welcome"
    username: username
    passwd: passwd

    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        GridLayout:
            cols: 2
            Label:
                text: "Email: "
            TextInput:
                id: username
                multiline: False
            Label:
                text: "Password: "
            TextInput:
                id: passwd
                multiline: False
        Button:
            text: "Login"
            on_release:
                on_press: root.btn()
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
<HomeWindow>
    name: "homewindow"
    id: "homewindow"
    GridLayout:
        cols:1
        Button:
            text: "Homepage"
```

python file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.network.urlrequest import UrlRequest
import urllib
import urllib.parse

class SplashWindow(Screen):
    def switch(self, *args):
        self.parent.current = "welcome"

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        # called when this Screen is displayed
        Clock.schedule_once(self.switch, 2)

class WelcomeWindow(Screen):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    passwd = ObjectProperty(None)

    def btn(self):
        # print("Username:", self.username.text, "Password:", self.passwd.text)
        params = urllib.parse.urlencode({'username': self.username.text, 'password': self.passwd.text})
        headers = {'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
        req = UrlRequest('https://www.domain.local/login.asp', on_success=http_post_login,
                         req_body=params, req_headers=headers)
        req.wait()
        self.username.text = ""
        self.passwd.text = ""

class HomeWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")


def http_post_login(req, result):
    # print('Our data is posted!')
    # print(result)
    if result == "msg=&logged_in=1":
        # success on login, go to home screen
        print("success")
        WindowManager.current = 'homewindow'
    else:
        # go back to welcome page, and show error message
        # self.parent.current = "welcome"
        WindowManager.current = "welcome"


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WindowManager` is a class, and you must use an instance of that class to call its instance methods. And you must use the exact instance that is managing the `Screens` in you `App`. In your code, you should be able to do something like:

```
def http_post_login(req, result):
    # print('Our data is posted!')
    # print(result)
    wm = App.get_running_app().root
    if result == "msg=&logged_in=1":
        # success on login, go to home screen
        print("success")
        wm.current = 'homewindow'
    else:
        # go back to welcome page, and show error message
        # self.parent.current = "welcome"
        wm.current = "welcome"
```

---

Since you save the root in the `kv` variable, you could also do:

```
def http_post_login(req, result):
    # print('Our data is posted!')
    # print(result)
    if result == "msg=&logged_in=1":
        # success on login, go to home screen
        print("success")
        kv.current = 'homewindow'
    else:
        # go back to welcome page, and show error message
        # self.parent.current = "welcome"
        kv.current = "welcome"
```

But that is a bit fragile, and less general.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, your first example works wonderfully.